# I want to attach a downloaded shirt to a model but not distort the mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, bones

I want to adjust the shirt to fit on the model, both are downloaded and I just want to fix the arm situation without distorting the mesh

[image: I want to adjust the shirt to fit on the model, both are downloaded and I just want to fix the arm situation without distorting the mesh]

I want to put the shirt on the model (not an armature) without moving the vertices. Want the result to sort of be like 'snap to face' but snap to face doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried that: Parent the t-shirt to the armature, create a pin group that will be the part of the t-shirt that won't be affected by any physics, give a Collisions physic to the body

Comment: @moonboots what if it isn't an armature, I've been "blending" for like a month lol so i don't know whether it qualifies as one because its just an import from Sketchfab with no bones I think. I'm planning to rig it in Mixamo after I get the clothing right. Also in light of being relatively new I'm not sure how to create a pin group and I didnt' see the collisions physics and some things aren't really there on youtube. help, sosssss lol

Comment: so it's not clear what you mean by "attach the shirt without distorting mesh", attach what to what and what distortion?

Comment: I want to put the shirt on the model without the shirt looking warped (i.e moving the vertices) so make it look like I used snap to face but snap to face doesn't work

Comment: maybe try the Pose brush in Sculpt mode?

Comment: used grab and it kinda worked out well but pose might come in handy as well, thanks :)

Comment: I think the Pose brush is the best in your case, if you understand how it works